# Find all integer values $x$, such that $\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x+ \ldots+\sqrt{x}}} < n$, for any number of radicals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, nested-radicals

Consider an integer ${n}\ge{2}$. Find all integers $x$ such that, for any number of radicals: $$\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x+ \ldots+\sqrt{x}}}<n$$

I know that this problem is supposed to be solved using induction but I just can't figure out how. Assuming an infinite number of nested radicals I concluded that:
$$A=\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x+ \ldots+\sqrt{x}}}\implies A^2 = x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x+ \ldots+\sqrt{x}}}\implies A^2 = x+ A$$

Solving for A, we find that the inequality holds for all positive integer values of $x$, such that $x\le{n^2 - n}$, which seems to be in line with the solution.

Edit: I realise that I should have mentioned this earlier, but I was hoping for a clearer answer. This is the answer from my problems book, which I don't really understand:

*It is obvious that for $\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x+ \ldots+\sqrt{x}}}$ to exist, we must have $x\ge{0}$, and for it to be smaller than $n$ for any number of radicals it must be $n^2 > x$. By setting $u = n^2 -x$, we notice that $u$ is a positive integer.
Consequently, $n^2 < u(u+1)$ and because both of them are positive integers, it follows that $u\ge{n}$ and thus $x\le{n^2 -n}$.
Using induction on the number of radicals we conclude that for every positive integer the statement $x\le{n^2 -n}$ true. Therefore $x\in{\{0, 1, \dots, n^2 -n\}}$.*

Can you please help me clarify the proof process. The parts I don't understand specifically are how the author arrives at the inequality $n^2 < u(u+1)$ and how he uses induction on the number of radicals.

Comment: Note:  you have only computed $A$ under the assumption that it exists. A priori, the infinite iteration might diverge.  For a fixed $x$, let $A_n$ denote the expression with $n$ radicals, so $A_n=\sqrt {x+A_{n-1}}$.  Now argue that the sequence of $A_n$ converges.

Comment: Well, I would like to ditch the infinite radical approach altogether, since this is from a collection of contest problems which ideally should be solvable without using limits or criteria of convergance.

Comment: It's the same problem.  You need to show that $A_{n-1}<A_n$ so that this is an increasing sequence bounded by $A$.